# laravel react api : request doesn't arrived

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, laravel-5, request

i'm using laravel api backend with react frontend .. i'm trying to post data using axios but request dose not arrived .. here is my code in frontend

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
 state = {
   product_name: '',

 }

 handleChange = event => {
   this.setState({ product_name: event.target.value });

 }

 handleSubmit = event => {
   event.preventDefault();

   const user = {
     product_name: this.state.product_name,



   };

   axios.post(`http://46.185.162.125/api/add_product`, { user })
     .then(res => {
       console.log(res);
       console.log(res.data);
     })
     .catch(error => {
   console.log(error.response)
});
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <label>
           Name:
           <input type="text" name="product_name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         </label>

         <button type="submit">Add</button>
       </form>
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

and this is the code of backend controller

```
public function addProduct(Request $request)
{
        $new_product = new Product;
        $new_product->name = $request->product_name;
        $new_product->save();

        return 'success';
 }
```

but i get 500 error (product_name column can't be null )
and this error occurred because request dose not  arrived

> I trying this api on postman and it worked

How can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `{ user }` is a shorthand for `{ user: user }`, so just send `user` as your data instead:

```
axios.post(`http://46.185.162.125/api/add_product`, user)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
```

Comment: @AhmadAboZaid Awesome! No problem. Welcome to stackoverflow!